# Modify a record when sending out an email template

Tags: apex, email-template

Setup:
The overall setup is that from Opportunity:

1. I’d like to choose a specific email template
2. Give the user the ability to update it.
3. Once it’s sent, update the opportunity custom field  with  some text.

Attempts:

1. I created a custom button on the Activity History launching the specific email template and some params.  In the trigger, I tried accessing the URL, but I can’t access it, like you can with VF and Controllers.
2. I tried to set the value of a Standard or  Custom Field on the Task by URL hacking (&field_id=123) and detect it in the trigger- but that wasn't useful (the field wasn't on the email template page).  I'm not sure if i did it right though...

`/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}&p2_lkid={!Opportunity.AccountId}&template_id=00Xe0000000DuS3&retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}&new_template=1&00Ne0000000rEDO=true&tsk12=Deferred`

Trigger:

```
Trigger TaskTrigger on Task (before insert) {

for(Task t: trigger.new){
    system.debug(t.status);
  //SHOWS AS COMPLETED... Native functionality??
}
}
```

/* Attempt 2

```
Trigger TaskTrigger on Task (before insert) {
for(Task t: trigger.new){

    String whatId = t.whatId;

    if (whatId.startsWith('006')){
        system.debug('referer = '+ apexpages.currentpage().geturl());
        if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('flag')== 'true' ){
            Opportunity opp = [select id from Opportunity where id = :t.whatId];
            opp._Transmitted__c = 'test';
            update opp;
        }
    }
}
```

`

I'm not sure if these should work, but it didn't.  HELP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the way to do this is as follows.

1. have the saveURl=/apex/aNewHelperVFPage?id=oppid&helperParamaters

when you land at the new vf page, in the the controller update the opportunity/record

then redirect the user back to the opportunuty/record